# Swiper last slide image is not centered

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I am using Swiper (Vue) and I have a use case that I can't figure out:
I have really wide images in my slider (together with some really narrow ones). My last image is a wide one.
I am trying to center that last image (Swiper cuts it right now)[image: Swiper last image]

These are my Swiper Options:

```
breakpoints: {
      0: {
        spaceBetween: 8,
      },
      [Breakpoint.tablet]: {
        spaceBetween: 20,
      },
      [Breakpoint.desktop]: {
        spaceBetween: 20,
      },
    },
    centerInsufficientSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
```

I played around with some other Options but can't find something that will solve this.
I can manually drag the image to see the rest of it, but I would like for it to be automatically scrolled and if it doesn't fit to be cut on the left side instead.